# MutableStateFlow collector doesn't receive data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, kotlin-stateflow

I have some view model:

```
    private val locationFlow = locationProviderClient.locationFlow(LocationModule.locationRequest)

    val position = MutableStateFlow(Location(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
    val positions = MutableStateFlow(emptyList<Position>())

    init {
        collectLocation()
    }

    private fun collectLocation() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            locationFlow.collect {
                position.value = it
                positions.value = positionService.updateLocation(it.toPosition())
            }
        }
    }
```

On initialization flow of current location is starting. On each new value last position should be emitted into `position` state flow and network request should be performed.
Here's fragment code responsible for collecting state flows

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
                ...
                viewModel.positions.collect(updateMarkers)
                viewModel.position.collect(updateCamera)
                ...
            }
}
```

Now, when fragment starts location is emitted, both flows are updated, request is send `updateMarkers` is called but `updateCamera` is not.

I suppose there is some subtle bug, if no can anybody tell me what the hell I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where is updateCamera function?

Comment: `collect` is a suspend function, you should call it in different coroutines (launch)

Comment: @charlie.7 ```private val GoogleMap.updateCamera: suspend (Location) -> Unit
        get() = { animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(it.toLatLng(), ZOOM_STREETS)) }``` it is working like it should but - but not called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collects of your two flows are not concurrent, they are still executed sequentially.

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                ...
                viewModel.positions.collect(updateMarkers)
                ...
            }

        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                ...
                viewModel.position.collect(updateCamera)
                ...
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
                ...
                launch {
                   viewModel.positions.collect(updateMarkers)
                }
                launch {
                   viewModel.position.collect(updateCamera)
                }
                ...
            }
    }
```